# C++ error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++

the following piece of C++ code compiled two years ago in a suse 10.1 Linux machine.

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


inline double sqr(double x) { return x*x; }
enum   Direction { X,Y,Z };

inline Direction next(const Direction d)
{
  switch(d)
  {
  case X: return Y;
  case Y: return Z;
  case Z: return X;
  }
}

inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Direction d)
{
  switch(d)
  {
  case X: return os << "X";
  case Y: return os << "Y";
  case Z: return os << "Z";
  }
}
...
...
```

Now, I am trying to compile it on Ubuntu 9.10 and I get the error:

```
data.h:20: error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token
```

which is referred to the line of:

```
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Direction d)
```

the g++ used on this machine is:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.1 (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9)
```

Could you give me some hint about this error?

Thanks

P.D. If i do std::ostream, I get the errors:

```
data.h:20: error: declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function
data.h:20: error: ‘ostream’ was not declared in this scope
data.h:20: error: ‘os’ was not declared in this scope
data.h:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
```

Comment: Did you use `std::ostream` in the definition of `os` too? The errors you are getting now suggest that you didn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As everything in the C++ standard library, `ostream` lives in the `std` namespace, so it's `std::ostream`.

I believe that, if this used to compile, this was in error.

Comment: hi, i dothat, and then i get 

data.h:23: error: declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function
data.h:23: error: ‘ostream’ was not declared in this scope
data.h:23: error: ‘os’ was not declared in this scope
data.h:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’

Comment: @Werner: Not really. You should edit your question with new information. That said, use the backticks: \`code goes here\` to get *some* formatting: `code goes here`. I escaped the former backticks with a backslash.

Comment: If i do std::ostream, I get the errors:

`\
data.h:20: error: declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function
data.h:20: error: ‘ostream’ was not declared in this scope
data.h:20: error: ‘os’ was not declared in this scope
data.h:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
`\

Comment: @Werner: Technically it's not guaranteed that `<iostream>` includes `<ostream>` (although I have a hard time imagining how an implementation could define `std::cout` without doing so). So you should include `<ostream>`. Anyway, your `operator<<` for any type `T`  should then look like this: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&)`;

Comment: @Werner just add std:: to each occurrence of ostream, not only to the first.

Comment: The error message refers to a syntax error. How is it relevant to the definition of ostream?

Comment: @SOFe: If you were, in fact commenting on my answer, note that I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: I have no idea how `expected initializer before ‘&’ token` is relevant to whether qualifying with a namespace. That seemed to be an error that came from the parsing stage.

Comment: @SOFe: All syntax errors come from the parser. In this case, when it encounters an identifier `ostream`, it doesn't know what that is, so it produces a syntax error. Note that C++ is not a designed language, but one that grew out of an ugly one (C) by keeping attaching new syntax to it. The resulting language is very hard to parse, which is why the error messages sometimes are so hard to understand.

Answer (score 8):

The `ostream` class is part of the C++ standard iostream library, and is defined in the namespace `std`

so you probably should add `std::` before `ostream`
or

```
using namespace std;
```

but, as stated in one of the comments :

> You should never use `using namespace
>   std` in a header as it can propagate
>   to other files.

Comment: -1. You should **never** use `using namespace std` in a header as it can propagate to other files.

Comment: That's not a reason for not mentioning it in the answer, he could have the same problem in a cpp file (and there is good chances for it). Yet I agree I should have added a disclaimer :) I never do it myself so I didn't think about it -- fix done you can call back your down votes if you forgive me :)

Comment: @f4: Forgiven and removed. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

you are missing a semicolon

```
inline Direction next(const Direction d)
{
   switch(d)
   {
     case X: return Y;
     case Y: return Z;
     case Z: return X;
   }
}**;**//missing semicolon

inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Direction d)
{
  switch(d)
  {
     case X: return os << "X";
     case Y: return os << "Y";
     case Z: return os << "Z";
  }
}`
```

Comment: Why do you think he is missing a semi-colon on the first inline function, but not on the second?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put std:: in front of each occurrence of `ostream`. Also, you should take Direction as a reference (while in this case, it won't hurt):

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Direction& d)
```

Comment: What is the gain in handling a reference to an enum?  Whether passed as a reference or `int`, it'd be the same mount of data: 32 or 64-bits.

Comment: Passing built-ins or enums as a const reference is not such a good practice. Passing them by value, as in OP code, is perfectly good.

Comment: That's why I said: `(while in this case, it won't hurt) :-)`

Comment: It is not that it won't hurt: it just does not apply to this case.

Comment: Honestly, do you really think it will change anything? And as says sbi in one of his comment: ` Anyway, your operator<< for any type T should then look like this: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&);` This is the good practice when overloading operator<<.